# Fill column from other data in row being inserted

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to come up with a trigger that fills a column of a row that I insert/update with a score that depends on the the numeric values on other columns of that same row.

For example

```
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 1    | 2    | 1    | 3    | 1    |      |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

This is the row I want to insert, I would like to fill `col6` with a score calculated using the values of the other columns

```
(100 - avg(col1:col5)/4*100)
```

Can I do this through a trigger or procedure? Should I do this before or after the insert?

Comment: Which version of Oracle? From 11g you can use a virtual column. Otherwise you can have a view that does the calculation. Actually storing derived data is just duplicating what you already have; and you also need to define what should happen if any other value changes - were you planning on updating col6 in that case too?

Comment: Also, what happens if you're try to update one of the columns? does that change the value of col6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trigger would look like.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ti
 BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON yourtable
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   :new.col6 := 
      (  100
       -   (:new.col1 + :new.col2 + :new.col3 + :new.col4 + :new.col5)/ 5 * 100);
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

From Oracle 11g you can use a virtual column:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  col1 NUMBER,
  col2 NUMBER,
  col3 NUMBER,
  col4 NUMBER,
  col5 NUMBER,
  col6 NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( 100 - (col1+col2+col3+col4+col5)*5 ) VIRTUAL
);

INSERT INTO table_name ( col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 )
  VALUES ( 1, 2, 1, 3, 1 );
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

**Output**:

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4 COL5 COL6
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----
   1    2    1    3    1   60
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if the expression is to throw error, say divide by zero, what happens then? Does the row get inserted or updated?

Comment: The row will get inserted without exceptions and then the select query will throw an `ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero` exception - if this is going to occur then add a check constraint to the table to prevent it inserting the row where any divisor value will be zero.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way to avoid the possible null values that might exist. Thank you all for the precious help.

```
create or replace TRIGGER SCORE_SYMP_TRG 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON KOOS 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN



  :NEW.SCORE_SYMP := 100 - ROUND(((NVL(:NEW.S1,0) + NVL(:NEW.S2,0) + NVL(:NEW.S3,0) + NVL(:NEW.S4,0) + NVL(:NEW.S5,0) + NVL(:NEW.R6, 0) + NVL(:NEW.R7, 0))/(
                        NVL((NVL(:NEW.S1,0)/NVL(:NEW.S1,1)),0) + NVL((NVL(:NEW.S2,0)/NVL(:NEW.S2,1)),0) + NVL((NVL(:NEW.S3,0)/NVL(:NEW.S3,1)),0) + NVL((NVL(:NEW.S4,0)/NVL(:NEW.S4,1)),0)
                        + NVL((NVL(:NEW.S5,0)/NVL(:NEW.S5,1)),0) + NVL((NVL(:NEW.R6,0)/NVL(:NEW.R6,1)),0) + NVL((NVL(:NEW.R7,0)/NVL(:NEW.R7,1)),0)) /4)*100,0);


END;
```